# Allow text selection but don't show context menu in WkWebView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, webkit, wkwebview

I have a mobile app written in SwiftUI. The user should be able to select (highlight) text in a `WebView`, i.e. the blue handles should be shown:
[image: Highlighting]

But I don't want to show the context menu. Is this possible?

The "solutions" I have seen so far all disable text highlighting (e.g. [How to disable user selection in a WKWebView in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48467723/how-to-disable-user-selection-in-a-wkwebview-in-swift)).

For reference, my WebView is a `UIViewRepresentable` that creates a `WkWebView`.

I have tried injecting Javascript:

```
  let javascriptStyle = "var css = '*{-webkit-touch-callout:none;-webkit-user-select:none}'; var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; var style = document.createElement('style'); style.type = 'text/css'; style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css)); head.appendChild(style);"
  webView.evaluateJavaScript(javascriptStyle, completionHandler: nil)
```

And sending `nil` to the completion handler:

```
  func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, contextMenuConfigurationForElement elementInfo: WKContextMenuElementInfo, completionHandler: @escaping (UIContextMenuConfiguration?) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(nil)
    }
```

The first method will disable the selection completely, and the second method does not seem to have an effect.

Comment: Supposedly you can implement the `WKUIDelegate` method `webView(_:contextMenuConfigurationForElement:completionHandler:)` and call the completion handler with `nil` but it only seems to be called for links, not other text.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but as you said it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use this for selection

For reference you can see this link also

[How do I get the selected text from a WKWebView from objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846404/how-do-i-get-the-selected-text-from-a-wkwebview-from-objective-c)

```
webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "newSelectionDetected")

let scriptString = """
function getSelectionAndSendMessage()
{
    var txt = document.getSelection().toString() ;
    window.webkit.messageHandlers.newSelectionDetected.postMessage(txt);
}
document.onmouseup = getSelectionAndSendMessage;
document.onkeyup = getSelectionAndSendMessage;
document.oncontextmenu = getSelectionAndSendMessage;"""

let script = WKUserScript(source: scriptString, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
```

webView.configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(script)

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
// Use message.body here
```

}